# Printing the corresponding index, and column of Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

What's up, folks?!

I have a panda dataframe whose indexes, and columns are both numbered from 0 to 5, and prints the biggest 10 values in a descending order. How can I put together the index as well as the column of each one of those 10 values in a parentheses?!

Here's my code (the problem starts from the last 6 lines):

```
    def poisson_dist(mean1: float, mean2: float):
        goals_probabilities = np.zeros(shape = (2, 6))
        probability_grid = np.zeros(shape = (6, 6))
        for i in range(6):
            goals_probabilities[0][i] = poisson.pmf(k = i, mu = mean1)
            goals_probabilities[1][i] = poisson.pmf(k = i, mu = mean2)

        main_table = pd.DataFrame(data = {

            0: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][0] for i in range(6)],
            1: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][1] for i in range(6)],
            2: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][2] for i in range(6)],
            3: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][3] for i in range(6)],
            4: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][4] for i in range(6)],
            5: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][5] for i in range(6)],

        }, index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

        table_to_line = sorted({x for v in main_table.values for x in v}, reverse = True)[:10]
        seriesed = pd.Series(data = main_table)

        for e in range(0, 6):
            for i in range(0, 11):
                if str(main_table[e][e]) == str(table_to_line[i]):
                    main_table[e][e]

        return main_table[e][e].index + '' + main_table[e][e].column
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson

def poisson_dist(mean1: float, mean2: float):
    goals_probabilities = np.zeros(shape=(2, 6))
    probability_grid = np.zeros(shape=(6, 6))
    for i in range(6):
        goals_probabilities[0][i] = poisson.pmf(k=i, mu=mean1)
        goals_probabilities[1][i] = poisson.pmf(k=i, mu=mean2)

    main_table = pd.DataFrame(data={
        0: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][0] for i in range(6)],
        1: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][1] for i in range(6)],
        2: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][2] for i in range(6)],
        3: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][3] for i in range(6)],
        4: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][4] for i in range(6)],
        5: [goals_probabilities[0][i] + goals_probabilities[1][5] for i in range(6)],
    }, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

   
    table_to_line = main_table.unstack().nlargest(10)
  
    result = []
    for (col, idx), val in table_to_line.items():
        result.append(f"({idx}, {col}): {val}")

    return result

result = poisson_dist(2, 3)
for item in result
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to create a new dataframe indexed by the columns as well as the rows and then take [`nlargest(10)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) of that:

```py
res = df.stack().nlargest(10)
```

For this (random) input:

```
   0   1  2   3  4   5
0  7   6  1   5  2  10
1  8   2  4   7  6   9
2  4  10  2   4  6   3
3  8   3  9   8  0   4
4  3   0  4   1  5  10
5  8   6  0  10  8   7
```

This will give a Series:

```
0  5    10
2  1    10
4  5    10
5  3    10
1  5     9
3  2     9
1  0     8
3  0     8
   3     8
5  0     8
```

You can then use `res.index` to get the (index,column) coordinates of the maximum values, or `zip` with the values to get a list of both e.g.

```
zip(res.index, res)
```

Output (for my sample data):

```
((0, 5), 10),
((2, 1), 10),
((4, 5), 10), 
((5, 3), 10), 
((1, 5), 9), 
((3, 2), 9), 
((1, 0), 8), 
((3, 0), 8), 
((3, 3), 8), 
((5, 0), 8)
```